# Local notification doesn't pop with tap on action buttons

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification

I made local notifications and they work fine, except that they don't pop if I tap on action buttons. It pops if I tap on notification itself. Is there a way to change it? I want notification to pop when I tap on action buttons as well.

Here I configure notifications:

```js
    PushNotification.configure({
        onNotification: function(notification) {
            onNotificationOpened(notification)
            console.log('Opened notification:', notification)
        },

        permissions: {
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true
        },
        popInitialNotification: true,
        requestPermissions: true
    })
```

And here I check if action buttons were tapped:

```js
    function onNotificationOpened(notification) {
        if (notification.action == 'Yes') {
            cancelNotification(notification.id)
            // some code
             })
        } else {
            cancelNotification(notification.id)
            // some code
        }
    }
```

Another question I have about action buttons. No matter which one I choose, it opens my app. Is there a way to make action button like "Remind later" that will reschedule notification without opening the app?

Comment: I am facing the same problem

Comment: I still haven't solved it. If you find a solution, please, let me know. I'll do the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing a local notification and want to pop out the notification when an action button is pressed, you can use the invokeApp prop. In react-native-push-notification documentation, it says

> This enable click on actions to bring back the application to
> foreground or stay in background, default: true

set invokeApp : false to pop out the notification without opening the app, for example

```
PushNotification.localNotification({
    message: "My Notification Message", 
    channelId: "firebase-channel", 
    foreground: true, 
    actions: ["Accept", "Reject"], 
    invokeApp : false
});
```